# Why didn't I receive two emails to merge my accounts?

Tags: bug, merge-accounts

I know I can merge my SO accounts in the contact page. I followed the instructions, also changed my accounts about me to "merge me" and confirmed the owner of each account. I only receive this kind of email:

> Hello,
>
> We received your request to merge the following Stack Overflow
>   accounts:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/users/5066707/klaider-klai
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/users/4976005/hand-on-cloud
>
> Before we can merge, we need to confirm that you own both of these
>   accounts. To confirm ownership of Klaider Klai, click the link below:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/contact/merge/26af05df00ed40b697b0c048ca6a092b
>
> We have sent an identical email to confirm ownership of your other
>   account. You have 48 hours to click the links in both emails. Once you
>   do, you'll be presented with the option to merge accounts.
>
> If you didn't receive the other email, or are having any other merge
>   problems, go to our contact form and select 'Other'. If you have
>   changed your mind about the merge or are receiving this email by
>   mistake, feel free to ignore it.
>
> Thanks,
>
> The Stack Exchange Team

I don't receive the another email.

Comment: Did you "go to our contact form and select 'Other'" then?

Comment: @RoberTLongson Yes... I did this yesterday.

Comment: They are probably just busy then. I'm sure they'll get to you.

Comment: @RobertLongson But they send me a email for me yesterday saying almost the same thing, but they said to change the 'about me' to "merge me".

Comment: Did you by chance use a dummy email for http://stackoverflow.com/users/4976005/hand-on-cloud?

Comment: @NathanOliver Nope... it's normal (from Google).